# Piped Logs in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, logs, pipe

Can someone walk me though how the data flows? Need to understand how I can intercept the log data, make changes to that data in situ, then save to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are written by the Apache httpd binary itself:

```
[root@cms_publish httpd]# fuser access_log
access_log:            488  1762  1842  4166  4167  4459  4460  4464  4634  5274  6679  7036  7120  7905  7980  8165  9290  9374  9375  9376 25534 26170 27463 29600
[root@cms_publish httpd]# ps -efa | grep 1762
apache    1762  1842  0 15:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     10434 10309  0 15:32 pts/0    00:00:00 grep 1762
[root@cms_publish httpd]#
```

There are [plenty of directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) that govern how and what Apache httpd will log. Too many to really list here. If you're looking to manipulate, you may try to either do something with a third party module to put it in some format you can manipulate (such as `mod_log_sql`) or you can give `TransferLog` or `CustomLog` a pipe and deal with it that way.

I think that addresses what you're asking. Is that enough information for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to pipe the output of the access log, manipulate it with sed, then output that to a file. Coming from the httpd daemon, is the data STDOUT or STDIN?

Comment: STDOUT from the perspective of `httpd` but STDIN from the perspective of whatever executable you're piping towards.

Comment: @dperry1973 why don't you just parse the logfile after or while it is written to?

Comment: @terdon The app server's HTTP URL requests (which is proxied through Apache) has stuff we would rather leave out. I tried while and created a mess where the data was being written 4x over in the access log.

Comment: @dperry1973 OK, I thought JosephR's answer to your question yesterday had solved that.

Comment: why not just modify your web app so that it doesn't log sensitive information, and doesn't include such info in the URLs?  i.e. fix the problem at the source rather than patch over it later.  if your devs need extra debugging info then that should be enabled on test and dev servers, but disabled on production servers.

Comment: I think the sensitive information is being passed via GET so it shows up in access_log without ever hitting the webapp. We also don't know if this is a third party product so development may be out of reach for the OP.